# difference_type in legacy random-access iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

If you check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) you will see:

> n, an integer of type difference_type

`difference_type` is (usually) a signed type, which means it (usually) can represent negative values. I have never encountered a test case, where STL algorithms would supply a negative value though. Can I assume that a positive value is always going to be supplied? If not, can you  provide a test case?

EDIT: negating a supplied `n` in an iterator implementation can be unsafe, as it can overflow. Maybe there exists a trick where I could do `size_type(-n)` and the result would still be correct (i.e. I'm concerned about sign extension).

Comment: You can pass a negative value to [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to move backwards.

Comment: And `std::distance` can of course return negative values.

Comment: oh nice one, `std::distance()`, but the implementation could be smart enough to circumvent negation in some cases, i.e. it could test < and then measure distance from the smaller iterator and then negate, if necessary.

Comment: @user1095108 But the whole point of `std::distance` is to give the correctly signed distance. The point of `difference_type` is to be able to represent the signed distance between iterators as a generalization of `ptrdiff_t` for differences of pointers.

Comment: I'm concerned about overflow, that's all, I did my homework on iterators, but I think I implemented many in a wrong way :) lol.

Comment: I don't really understand what overflow you are concerned about. The only valid values for `n` are those, for which advancing the iterator, forward or backward according to the sign, `abs(n)` times, is possible. So `abs(n)` can never be larger than the size of the iterator range and conversely you can't have a random-access iterator range so large that not both +size and -size can be represented in `difference_type`.

Comment: @user17732522 yes, that's what the Standard says, but I'd like to accommodate everyone. In essence, I'm concerned about sign extension, that's all. So, if size_type > difference type, will I get a huge n, if I negate the minimum n and then convert to `size_type` (i.e. `size_type(-n)`).

Comment: @user1095108 You will only get that if the size of the iterator range is that large and in that case your iterator can't satisfy the legacy random-access iterator requirements with that choice of types for `size_type` and `difference_type`. It should be impossible to create such an iterator in the first place, e.g. no container is allowed to be that large.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not concerned about actual size of my container, just the fact that size_type can be > and usually is > than difference_type, but ok, it's probably UB, like every overflow, what I had in mind, so I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I assume that a positive value is always going to be supplied? If not, can you provide a test case?

No, you cannot assume that. A trivial example is applying `std::reverse_iterator` to your iterator and then calling any standard library algorithm that would actually use random access, e.g. `std::binary_search`.

`std::reverse_iterator` has to negate any offset requested by the algorithm before passing it onto the underlying iterator.

Comment: I tried `std::sort()` and some others and they only provided positive values, but ok.

Comment: @user1095108 OK, I had a look and the standard library implementations of `std::reverse_iterator` seem to prefer calling `-` and `-=` on the underlying iterator. But e.g. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xutility#L1416) is Microsoft's STL negating an offset for `std::reverse_iterator::operator[]`. Which way the implementations choose is up to them and could change without notice.